# Can I test Video Chat on Multiple Devices / Browsers

Tags: cypress

My company has a software that uses Vonage’s (Formerly Tok Box) video chat API to provide live video chat between patients and physicians online.

I am looking for a cross browser / device testing solution that I can test the video chat across multiple browsers and devices to verify the video chat is working correctly across these devices.

Does your testing software allow me to access cameras on different browsers /devices  for testing video chat in our online software application?